Dynamic query across multiple tables in supabase?
I am trying to use an input box to search across multiple tables in react with supabase but not having much luck. Any ideas?
    const fetchLeads = async () => {
      let query = supabase
      .from('lead')
      .select(`
        lead_id, 
        progress, 
        sales_status, 
        comments, 
        person:person_id (
          first_name, last_name, email, phone
        ),
        property:property_id (
          street_address, post_code
        )
      `);
  
    // Server-side search logic across the person and property tables
    if (searchTerm) {
      query = query.or(
        `person.first_name.ilike.%${searchTerm}%,person.last_name.ilike.%${searchTerm}%,property.street_address.ilike.%${searchTerm}%,property.post_code.ilike.%${searchTerm}%`
      );
    }

The logic isn't parsing with Supabase. I have tried multiple variants but no luck. The closest I got was using or like this but this only bring back data in the specific table, instead of both tables.
// Server-side search logic using `ilike` across the person and property tables
    if (searchTerm) {
      query = query
        .or(`first_name.ilike.%${searchTerm}%,last_name.ilike.%${searchTerm}%`, { foreignTable: 'person' })
        .or(`street_address.ilike.%${searchTerm}%,post_code.ilike.%${searchTerm}%`, { foreignTable: 'property' });
    }

